# Change name of database on Docker and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm a complete Docker novice, and for learning purposes I'm trying to start a basic rails project with Docker.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.5 
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app 
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /app
```

and here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    db: 
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: app
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
    app: 
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes: 
            - ".:/app"
        ports: 
            - "3001:3000"
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
        environment:
            DB_USER: root
            DB_NAME: app
            DB_PASSWORD: password
            DB_HOST: db
```

And here's my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

This is working perfectly. Now if I change the name of the database through setting `MYSQL_DATABASE: hello` and `DB_NAME: hello` in docker-compose.yml, the app crashes. Rails throws an error `Unknown database 'hello'`

I'm not doing anything different in the two cases, the only difference is the name in the file, the startup steps though are the same. What is causing this error?! Or where else should I change the name of the database to make it work?

Comment: You might have to remove your mysql container..

Comment: Why? can you elaborate pls? :D @LinFelix

Comment: Compose [reuses containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#only-recreate-containers-that-have-changed), so maybe it uses the container where `MYSQL_DATABASE` is still `app`